Caching Pages While Ignoring Specific URL Parameters
I am new to Magento and developing a website where certain URL parameters are unique, but do not affect the page content. For example:
User 1 visits: example.com/product/view?id=123&example=xyz123
User 2 visits: example.com/product/view?id=123&example=abc456
In this scenario, the example parameter is unique but does not change the content of the page.
I want to ensure that pages are cached based on their content, ignoring certain parameters like "example" that do not affect the content, so that users can benefit from cached versions of identical pages.
I tried searching in Magento vendor directories for a function i can than modify or create a custom module, but with no success. Im working with community version and using build-in cache.
